# How to check for a element in LIst in goovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have:

```
List list = [3,5,6]
```

now i want to check whether the List has element "3" .when i do:

```
list.contains("3")
```

it returns false ,so how to do  this

Comment: The answer is correct. What should it return in your opinion?

Answer (score 8):

As others have mentioned the problem with your code is that the list contains the Integer 3, not the String "3". To check for the Integer 3, use either:

```
[1, 2, 3].contains(3)
```

or

```
3 in [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Although I do not know groovy I think that you should try `list.contains(3)`, i.e. value without quotes. It is because you actually created list of integer elements and then trying to look for string into the list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know groovy that much, but your list seems to contain integers and you check for a string. Try `list.contains(3)`.